# Cerrar sistema al cerrar sesion de windows

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017, directorioactivo

Tengo un sistema winforms que utiliza el mismo  usuario y password para iniciar sesion de windows usando las credenciales del Active Directory.
Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario por ejemplo cierre su sesion de windows o teclee las teclas Ctrl + Alt + Del y seleccione Lock al mismo tiempo se cierre el sistema winforms y regrese el login la proxima vez que inicie sesion en windows o desbloque su sesion.

Como puedo hacer eso?

El sistema esta hecho en C# utilizando VS2012 professional.
Espero que se entienda lo que busco.

EDITADO

Con este codigo se bloque la sesion de windows, entonces lo que quiero es detectar cuando se llame a este evento o metodo y si se cumple entonces llamar a cerrar mi formulario o sistema tambien.

```
 [DllImport("user32")]
public static extern void LockWorkStation();

LockWorkStation();
```

Comment: Yo al menos no lo entiendo muy bien. Lo que quieres es que cuando se bloquee la sesion en el equipo, tu aplicación tambien se bloquee pasando a tu formulario de login?

Comment: Exacto es lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Invertiras recursos intentando capturar el evento y para versiones de windows diferentes , es mejor que si tu aplicacion no tiene interaccion con el usuario por digamos 5 min, esta se vaya a tu formulario de login.